# Creating realistic shadow of an irregular object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shadows

Can someone either point me to a tutorial on how to do this or tell me how? I'm working on an illustration of headphones and I need to make it look as thought the wire coming out of the headphones is sitting on a table and the light source is above and casting the shadow slightly to the left.I did the below test but it looks more like you are looking at the wire from an x/y axis. Any help? Thanks!

[image: example]

Comment: You've got a pretty good start. I think what you're missing is an actual shadow on the wire. Because without it, it just looks flat, but the shadow underneath is good in my opinion!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a camera, headphones, and a desk lamp, then set it up and take the shot! Then study how the lighting affects the headphone cable. It's better to work from real life than to try and make it work, particularly if you don't already have experience doing so.

As Johannes said in his comment, the wire needs a shadow.

Depending on where the light source is and how strong it is, you might also benefit a gradient that maybe makes the left side a bit darker than the right. Finally, if you do something like that, then the table could use some gradation as well.

Your current shadow is pretty good, slight pixelation aside. It *might* benefit you to have some ever-so-slight shadowing where the cord hits the table as well. Even if something's flat on the table, it's probably doing some kind of casting.